# Source of Satellite and Debris Ephemerides for Analysis

Tags: orbital-mechanics, debris, ephemeris

I'm working on some code that will fuse ephemeris data, the raw telescope and radar data used for locating and tracking active satellites and space debris.  Most of this data is owned by the Air Force and commercial companies.  Are there any more readily available sources for this data on the Internet?  I was thinking Amateur Astronomy or educational institutions may publish this data?

Comment: I think you're looking for sources like Heavens Above (https://www.heavens-above.com/), Celestrak (https://celestrak.com/), SpaceTrack (https://www.space-track.org/auth/login), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  these sites have Elsets, or TLEs, products of the ephemerides which is fused together to get orbital determination.  I'm looking for the raw data that produces these.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using "ephemerides" in a sub-optimal way? I think you are looking for "the raw telescope and radar data". To my understanding, this data is then processed and a trajectory fit to it as a series of state vectors, and then a simple parameterized model fit to that to extract TLE's, and it's either the table of state vectors or the TLEs that can be called ephemerides. Have I got that wrong?

Comment: you have that right, i'm looking for the raw telescope and radar data; the ephemeris (epoch, X,Y,Z,dX,dY,dZ).  I would like to process this myself with some Initial Orbit Determination (IOD) software.  The TLE as an input to a propagator such as SGP4 will spit out 'future' ephemeris,